# how to select different colorbox styles for different content types in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, javascript

i tried to select different colorbox styles for different content types but i couln't. because we can select only one colorbox style for all using.

if onybody know how can select different colorbox style for different content type please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it from admin UI. 
Formatter settings also has no option to select style for current image display.

But you can try the following:

```
function [themename]_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['type'] == 'node_type' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    variable_set('colorbox_style', 'stockholmsyndrome');
  } else {
    variable_set('colorbox_style', 'default');
  }
}
```

Yep, it's dirty hack, but it can helps... maybe... =)

Comment: thanks, this solves the problem. but if we update drupal? you say "if ($vars['type'] == 'node_type' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'full')" in code. if i have a lot of view modes what can i do for support all? thanks again

Comment: Trying to explain.
There is not a perfect solution, but it works. 

If you update core or colorbox module, this functionality still works. If you wanna normal solution, that can be managed through  UI you should implement `hook_field_formatter_settings_form()` & `hook_field_formatter_view()` and override colorbox default formatters